# Flutter String, dynamic'is not a subtype of type

Tags: flutter

When try go to details page get this error:

type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'User'

```
onTap: (){
       print(posts['items'][index]); //return flutter ( 4824): {empno: 7839, ename: KING....
       Navigator.push(context,
       new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(posts['items'][index]))
      );
},


class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final User user;

  DetailPage(this.user);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(user.ename),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a User model like this

```
class User {
  final String empno;
  final String ename;

  User({this.empno, this.ename});
}
```

you need to pass User to Details page not Map. Try

```
onTap: (){
       print(posts['items'][index]); 
       User _user = User(
           empno: posts['items'][index].empno
           ename: posts['items'][index].ename
       );
       print(_user);
       Navigator.push(context,
       new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(_user))
      );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the `print()` function, the result of `posts['items'][index]` is `{empno: 7839, ename: KING...`. In the DetailPage constructor you are waiting for the `User` object, and you are passing the HashMap. You have to pass an User object to this constructor to make it work. Otherwise, if you want to pass this LinkedHashMap your code should look something like this:

```
class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final Map<String, dynamic> user;

  DetailPage(this.user);

  ...
}
```

And later you will be able to access every element of this map by key.